# Prevent inserting duplicate values in Database

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I prevent duplicate data inserting in database?

What I like is when click button save it will show message "Cannot Insert Duplicate Value". I'm using MSAcess for my database.

Code:

```
                connection1.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = connection1.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into Taxation (ShoesBrand, ShoesCode, ShoesColor) Values (ShoesBrand, ShoesCode, ShoesColor)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ShoesBrand", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ShoesCode", textBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ShoesColor", textBox3.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection1.Close();
```

How do I prevent not to insert same value? Or how can i add to throw exemption when values are the same in database.

Comment: That is the responsibility of the database - you should have a unique constraint in the database itself, and call `ExecuteNonQuery` inside a `try` block to handle possible exceptions

Comment: Is this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a unique index on the required column of the table. in this way, It will not allow you to insert duplicate records from C# code.

You can learn more about Unique constraints [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/constraint-clause-microsoft-access-sql).

Few points to be noted here. you should use `using` when initializing the connection. and please read about SQL injections.